# Why is my C program not showing any output in the terminal when I try to find the youngest person's age among three given ages?

Tags: c, if-statement, logical-and, relational-operators

the terminal is showing no output (blank)

```
// if the ages of 3 people are put telling which one is youngest//

#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a1,a2,a3;

    printf("enter the age of ram,shyam and ajay");
    scanf("%d,%d,%d",&a1,&a2,&a3);

    if(a1>a2>a3)
        printf("%d,%d,%d",a1,a2,a3);
    if(a3>a2>a1)
        printf("%d,%d,%d",a3,a2,a1);
    if(a2>a1>a3)
        printf("%d,%d,%d",a2,a1,a3);
    if(a2>a3>a1)
        printf("%d,%d,%d",a2,a3,a1);
    if(a1>a3>a2)
        printf("%d,%d,%d",a1,a3,a2);
    if(a3>a1>a2)
        printf("%d,%d,%d",a3,a1,a2);

    return 0;
}
```

i am not sure if you should write 3 expressions in an if statement like 1>2>3
please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Please note that your code would be easier to read (both for yourself and for other people) if you applied [indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style). I have added it for you.

Comment: Please provide an example of the exact input that is causing the problem. For example, does your input have the format `12,21,18` or `12 21 18`?

Comment: Input is like 12,13,14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
if(a1>a2>a3)
```

will not do what you want. According to the [rules of operator precedence and associativity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), that expression is equivalent to the following:

```
if ( (a1>a2) > a3 )
```

The sub-expression `(a1>a2)` will evaluate to either `0` (false) or `1` (true). Therefore, the entire expression is equivalent to either

```
if ( 0 > a3 )
```

or:

```
if ( 1 > a3 )
```

What you want is instead the following:

```
if ( ( a1 > a2 ) && ( a2 > a3 ) )
```

Because the `&&` operator has lower precedence than the `>` operator according to the rules mentioned above, you can write this without the parentheses:

```
if ( a1 > a2 && a2 > a3 )
```

Another problem in your solution is that if all 3 input values are identical, then none of the `if` statements will be true, and your program will print nothing.

I suggest that you rewrite your logic like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int a1, a2, a3;

    printf( "Enter the age of ram,shyam and ajay: " );
    scanf( "%d,%d,%d", &a1, &a2, &a3 );

    if ( a1 > a2 )
    {
        if ( a2 > a3 )
        {
            printf( "%d,%d,%d\n", a1, a2, a3 );
        }
        else
        {
            if ( a1 > a3 )
            {
                printf( "%d,%d,%d\n", a1, a3, a2 );
            }
            else
            {
                printf( "%d,%d,%d\n", a3, a1, a2 );
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ( a1 > a3 )
        {
            printf( "%d,%d,%d\n", a2, a1, a3 );
        }
        else
        {
            if ( a2 > a3 )
            {
                printf( "%d,%d,%d\n", a2, a3, a1 );
            }
            else
            {
                printf( "%d,%d,%d\n", a3, a2, a1 );
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Because every `if` statement now has a corresponding `else` statement, all cases are handled, including the case of all 3 numbers being identical.

This solution is also more efficient, because the maximum number of comparisons required is now only 3 instead of 12.

Alternatively, if you put all numbers into an array, you can sort the array and then print it. This will make things a lot easier when you have more than 3 numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int my_compare( const void *left, const void *right )
{
    int a = *(int*)left;
    int b = *(int*)right;

    if ( a < b )
        return 1;
    if ( a > b )
        return -1;

    return 0;
}

int main( void )
{
    //define array with many numbers
    int arr[] = { 14, 17, 19, 18, 17, 12, 15, 19 };
    const int arr_size = sizeof arr / sizeof *arr;

    //sort the array
    qsort( arr, arr_size, sizeof *arr, my_compare );

    //print the content of the sorted array
    for ( int i = 0; ; )
    {
        printf( "%d", arr[i] );
        if ( ++i == arr_size )
            break;
        printf( ", " );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
19, 19, 18, 17, 17, 15, 14, 12
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes! You can't use the statement like this: `if (a1>a2>a3)`, you need to write them like this:

```c
if (a1>a2 && a2>a3)
```

And also one more thing you need to correct in this program that you need to check the conditions only once for one variable or also you can also take a look on the function by you can do it easily without writing that much much code within some lines you can solve it.

Answer (score 2):

According to the C Standard (6.5.8 Relational operators)

> 6 Each of the operators < (less than), > (greater than), <= (less than
> or equal to), and >= (greater than or equal to) **shall yield 1 if the
> specified relation is true and 0 if it is false**. The result has
> type int.

And the operators are evaluated from left to right,

So if statements like that

```
if(a1>a2>a3)
```

are equivalent to

```
if( ( a1 > a2 ) > a3 )
```

And depending on whether `a1` is greater than `a2` or not you have either

```
if( ( 1 ) > a3 )
```

or

```
if( ( 0 ) > a3 )
```

Instead you need to include in the expression logical AND operator like

```
if( a1 > a2 && a1 > a3 )
```

But if you will do so the program can output nothing if at least two ages are equal each other.

Also in this call of `scanf`

```
scanf( "%d,%d,%d", &a1, &a2, &a3 );
```

it is better to remove commas between the conversion specifiers. Let the user will enter ages separated by spaces like for example

```
20 22 21
```

or

```
20
22
21
```

If you want to output the ages in the descending order you could write for example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int a1, a2, a3;

    printf( "enter the age of ram,shyam and ajay: " );
    scanf( "%d %d %d", &a1, &a2, &a3 );

    if ( a1 < a2 )
    {
        int tmp = a1;
        a1 = a2;
        a2 = tmp;
    }

    if ( a2 < a3 )
    {
        int tmp = a2;
        a2 = a3;
        a3 = tmp;
    }
 
    if ( a1 < a2 )
    {
        int tmp = a1;
        a1 = a2;
        a2 = tmp;
    }

    printf( "%d, %d, %d\n", a1, a2, a3 );
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. In case anyone is interested, the sorting algorithm used in this answer is very similar to [exchange sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Exchange_sort).